# Which adventure should I start in Pathfinder: Wrath of the Righteous Adventure Card Game?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

I've heard I should start with Adventure B, but it's a really hard adventure! Is this really true? Or should I start with the seemingly easier Adventure 1?

To clarify: What is the "official" starting adventure in Pathfinder: Wrath of the Righteous? Or is there an official one?

Comment: @Othya - Opinion based questions are fine as long as those opinions are based on "facts, references, or specific expertise"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paizo has actually admitted that Wrath of the Righteous ended up a little harder than intended. In particular, the B scenarios are considered by some to be harder than the #1 scenarios.

Fortunately, [this is addressed in the FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1h4#v5748eaic9u1s):

> Resolution: Make one or both of these changes only if you're looking for an easier time with Wrath B scenarios:
>
> On the B and C henchman Tangle Trap, add the line "If defeated, you may immediately attempt to close the location this henchman came from."
>
> Move some or all of the following cards from Set B and/or C to Set 1, and change their set indicators to 1: the barrier Arboreal Blight (B & C), the monster Carrion Golem (B & C), and 1 of the Demonic Horde barriers in B and/or the Demonic Horde barrier currently in C. Then move some or all of the following cards from Set 1 to Set B, and change their set indicators to B: the monster Accursed Priest and the barrier Poisoned Spiked Pit Trap.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the errata. I'm more asking what the official starting adventure should be?

Comment: I believe in all the base sets, the B adventures are recommended but not required. They can be nice in that they give you time to get used to your character and get some deck upgrades. But the WotR B adventure is very hard, and so some may prefer to skip it, if the rewards aren't worth it.